# Вывести содержимое папки powershell

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

У меня есть папка А,которая содержит в себе несколько папок,каждая из которых имеет в себе несколько текстовых файлов.
Мне необходимо написать скрипт powershell,который выводит названия текстовых файлов в отдельный файл в таком формате.

```
Название папки 1
файл1.txt
файл2.txt
Название папки 2
a.txt
b.txt
Название папки 3
e.txt
aa.txt
```

Путь к папке А и текстовому файлу(в котором будет сохранена вся информация) передаются как аргументы командной строки.

```
$papka=args[0] $resultfile=args[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $args[0] -Directory |
ForEach-Object{
    $_.Name;
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Name -Filter "*.txt";
} |
Out-File -FilePath $args[1]
```

Comment: необходимо добавить Filter  на txt   `Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Name  -Filter "*.txt"`